# Counting and sorting in C

Tags: c, counting

I'm dabbling around with a regular C program that counts a number of inputs and categorizes them accordingly. I don't really have any code written up for it right now since I am still thinking of how to go about it, so I'll do my best to explain.

As an example of where I want to go with this program, lets say I want it to count the number of votes from people. I'm only interested in the demographics, not the actual votes. So, the user inputs the gender and age of each person with an individual ballot which then adds to a total number at the end and tallies between male and female. There would be a character assigned to each age bracket to help with the tally. For example ages 0-20 = A, 21-40 = B, 41+ = C. Then, there would be an input like X0 which would end the counting:

So it would look something like this with the gender and ages as the user input (ignore bullets):

- Enter gender and age: Male 17
- Enter gender and age: Female 20
- Enter gender and age: Male 30
- Enter gender and age: Female 46
- Enter gender and age: Male 35
- Enter gender and age: X0
- Male: ABB
- Female: AC
- Total: 5

I'm thinking of using while, for, and do while loops to get this accomplished since I am still learning the language, but I am having a hard time getting this going.

If you guys have any advice, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch statements and if's and have counters to keep a count of votes. I would approach the problem like that. try doing it on paper and pen a little, write a little bit of code i am sure you will get it once u start with paper and pen. Also for sorting you can use a loop which can take of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just dive right in and write it the way you know how. Coding experience is very useful early on. If you can get something that works the way you describe, you'll learn a lot along the way just by doing the grunt work.

To get the output and input on one line like you describe, you may need to call `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` and before the `scanf`.

By the way, a common strategy for terminating user input to a program is with an EOF code (ctrl-D in Unix/Linux, ctrl-Z in Windows). `scanf` will return a negative value if it encounters EOF instead of more keyboard strokes.

That said, as a *broader* strategy, I'd recommend you start thinking about these sorts of programs as *non-interactive*. Imagine if the program didn't need to go through the questionnaire each time, but read the data straight from a file. And instead of full words, it would have single-letter codes and look more like

```
M 17
F 20
```

And the program *just did the counting.* Wouldn't that be easier to write *and use*?